# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method worked on the first IF line, but doesn't work on any others

Tags: python

I realize that there are similar questions, but none of the answers helped me.  I've written this program to sum up the names in a list and if I put `print(name_length_list[0])` below the first IF statement, it prints it just fine. **I'll upload the whole code so there's no confusion!**

```
name_number = 0
name_length_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
name_list = ["Jennifer","Albatross","Justin","Dave","Shankarnarayan","Ezra","Alice","Kwabena"]
  while (name_number<9):
    print(len(name_list[name_number]))
    name_number = name_number + 1
  if (name_number is 0):
    name_length_list["0":name_list[name_number]]
 >HERE is where I put the print statement that worked
  if (name_number is 1):
    name_length_list["1":name_list[name_number]]
  if (name_number is 2):
    name_length_list["2":name_list[name_number]]
  if (name_number is 3):
    name_length_list["3":name_list[name_number]]
  if (name_number is 4):
    name_length_list["4":name_list[name_number]]
  if (name_number is 5):
    name_length_list["5":name_list[name_number]]
  if (name_number is 6):
    name_length_list["6":name_list[name_number]]
  if (name_number is 7):
    name_length_list["7":name_list[name_number]]
    print(name_length_list["0"+"1"+"2"+"3"+"4"+"5"+"6"+"7"])
  if (name_number is 8):
    break

print("Code is done")
```

Comment: It's hard to figure out what your code is actually supposed to do. Please provide a description of the expected output so that we can help you find a solution that will actually do what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
name_length_list["0":name_list[name_number]]
```

You are using a string as the start index, it must be an integer (or `None`, or have an `__index__` method). Your end index is also a string.

Consider the following line:

```
name_length_list["0":name_list[name_number]]
```

Let's say `name_number` is `0`, the line is:

```
name_length_list["0":name_list[0]]
```

which is

```
name_length_list["0":"Jennifer"]
```

which means you are trying to extract the contents of `name_length_list` from index `"0"` to index `"Jennifer"`. The interpreter, of course, has no idea what that means.

Comment: So why did it let me print the first amount in the name_length_list? It gave me the amount I was looking for, which was 8

Comment: @bubbagubba because `print(len(name_list[name_number]))` is valid syntax; you're asking Python to print the `name_number` index (which is the number `0`) of the list `name_list` (the `0`th item being `'Jennifer'`), and then print the `len()` of that, which is 8. `name_length_list["0":name_list[1]]` (assuming `name_number` is `1`) means "get the items from the string '0' to the string 'Albatross' out of the list `name_length_list` and then do absolutely nothing with the result". It doesn't work to use strings as indexes in a list hence why what you're trying to ask Python to do throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain exactly what your code is trying to do but it seems like you're trying to print out the sum of all the lengths of all the names in `name_list`. The below code accomplishes that:

```
total_length = 0
name_list = ["Jennifer","Albatross","Justin","Dave","Shankarnarayan","Ezra","Alice","Kwabena"]

for name in name_list:
    total_length += len(name)

print(total_length)
print("Code is done")
```

Output:

> ```
> 57
> Code is done
> ```

The lines like `name_length_list["0":name_list[name_number]]` do nothing; there's no printing or assigning happening, so even if it was valid syntax to use a string as an index for a list, nothing would happen, still.

With `print(name_length_list["0"+"1"+"2"+"3"+"4"+"5"+"6"+"7"])`; that's just not how Python works at all. It seems like you think what that's doing is adding up the values of all the items in `name_length_list`. But what's happening is that you're concatenating all those strings together, meaning you're trying to print `name_length_list["0123456789"]`, which doesn't work in Python because again, you can't use a string as an index for a list.

If you want to use a list to store the name lengths, you can do it like so, and then use `sum()` to get the sum of the values in the list at the end:

```
name_list = ["Jennifer","Albatross","Justin","Dave","Shankarnarayan","Ezra","Alice","Kwabena"]
name_length_list = []

for name in name_list:
    name_length_list.append(len(name))

print(sum(name_length_list))
print("Code is done")
```

Output:

> ```
> 57
> Code is done
> ```

However, again because your question was unclear, as well as your code, I could be totally misinterpreting what you were trying/required to do, but I tried to understand what you meant and so gave an answer based on my understanding.